# Is this audit correct?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I [failed an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/12049637) for [Can I use Java annotations to define compile time checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36538133/781965)

I didn't look to see if there were answers or what they were because typically unless I'm unsure whether a question should be closed I don't bother - most questions in the close queue that I see are pretty obvious. In this case, it seemed clear to me that the question matches the following Off-Topic description:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

The question links to code outside of the question and asks "If someone could take a look and just explain a few things to me". Seems textbook to me, though plenty of research effort has been taken - I'm sure with a little effort a clear question statement could be edited in and they could probably provide a MCV example for it, but it doesn't currently seem like a good question. Am I wrong?

Comment: *The question links to code outside of the question and asks "If someone could take a look and just explain a few things to me".* So, you only read the last paragraph of the question?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No - that just seemed to me to be the culmination of the clarifications in the comments, and what resolved the issue seemed to be a discussion and reference to a bunch of tutorials (see the comments also). This was then posted later as an answer that seems to consist of some explanation, a tool recommendation and some subjective statements - it's not a bad answer, so I haven't since voted for the question to be closed, but I do feel it's a fairly close call. Not a big deal, but I thought we brought those up on here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is basically saying "I have some annotations and I want to run checks against the annotated elements.  How do I do that?", to which the answer is "Use an annotation processor, possibly building on the Checker Framework".  Because the asker doesn't know annotation processors exist and can do what they want, they're limited to giving examples of what they want to do, but the question is still clear enough for me (as someone who has worked with annotation processors) to immediately know what they're asking for.

The mention of an Eclipse plugin as one potential solution is the asker retreating to what they do know (their IDE), but finding it isn't a great solution.  I assume the asker added this in an attempt to show effort, not to *convert* their question from "How do I process annotations to perform checks?" to "How do I do [undefined stuff] in an Eclipse plugin?".  Indeed, the answer they accepted doesn't involve Eclipse plugins at all!  Closing their question as "debugging" feels to me like punishing them for mentioning they tried something that didn't happen to be the best solution to their problem.

Comment: Hmm, I think I titled my question wrong. I wasn't intending so much to ask if my treatment was fair or if the question should be closed as much as asking if this question should be used as a review audit. I think that the question could be improved dramatically by some fairly hefty edits (which IIRC would fail the audit as well) so it might not be a good idea use as an audit question, and I thought we raised things like that on meta... I could be wrong though, I don't spend much time here.